# FBO depth and stencil render buffer attachments

Tags: opengl

The OpenGL [wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) says that in order to use stencil buffer attachment with depth buffer in FBO one needs to create the render buffer with format of the type `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8`, as it seems like GL_STENCIL_INDEXX aren't implemented.

What I don't understand is whether such a buffer is also depth buffer if I set it as `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`? Or should I still create separate depth render buffer with formats (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENTXX)?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Linux/Windows OpenGL4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the STENCIL_INDEX formats aren't "implemented". It's that the specification does not *require* an implementation to consider them to be complete. Implementations are allowed to [reject a combination of image formats for whatever reasons it deems fit](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), *unless* you stick to the [list of required image formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Formats#Required_formats).

A depth/stencil image has depth and stencil in it, just like a red/green image has both red and green in it. So yes, you [attach the same image](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Object_Structure) to the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` and `GL_STENCIL_ATTACMENT` points. Or you use `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` as shorthand for both.

Comment: I actually tried using GL_STENCIL_INDEX and it always resulted in incomplete FBO. Also in the same wiki is said "DON"T DO IT!" ;)